# Could some of the ARM tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There are quite a few tags for questions about the ARM architecture, and partially due to somewhat confusing naming schemes of architecture version vs. processor family, some of these primarily contain mistagged questions.

You get ARMv7 questions tagged [arm7](/questions/tagged/arm7) instead of [armv7](/questions/tagged/armv7), Cortex-A9 questions tagged as [arm9](/questions/tagged/arm9) and the tag [arm6](/questions/tagged/arm6) which contains only one question which should have been tagged [armv6](/questions/tagged/armv6).

Would it be possible to get rid of the [arm6](/questions/tagged/arm6), [arm7](/questions/tagged/arm7), [arm9](/questions/tagged/arm9) and [arm11](/questions/tagged/arm11) tags and merge the existing questions into [arm](/questions/tagged/arm)?

Comment: This makes me think of http://www.photoarrow.com/duo/rag6306x640x427.jpg

Comment: Linus thinks it's to do with the local water supply: https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/7/15/133

Comment: Holy moly! It's no wonder that the taggers are confused.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins You should see the mess we have with Xcode...

Comment: I strongly disagree with merging everything into [tag:arm]. There's maybe more fragmentation than necessary, but at least some of them are useful. Even architecture versions are too coarse-grained, e.g. distinguishing between ARM11, Cortex-A, Cortex-R and Cortex-M is useful.

Comment: @Gilles: the suggestion is not to reduce precision. The suggestion is the observation that the currently provided number of different tags add confusion and leads to questions not being seen. And the vast majority of questions on ARM processor-family specific tags are incorrectly tagged, intending to be for an architecture version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many **ARM** related sub-tags.  Tools are available to the community to try to fix things.  We can propose and vote on [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) at reputation of 2500.  At a reputation of 2,000 [edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) allow you to re-tag questions.  If a tag has no existing question for one day, it will be deleted.

[Gilles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149076/gilles) has a point in that some sub-tagging is useful.  Although you may wish to follow all thing **ARM**, sometimes people will want specific information related to **MMU** and **ISA** issues which are for a specific **ARM** architecture revision.

Here is a list of existing **ARM** tags,

- [cortex-m3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-m3) - 188 questions.
- [cortex-a8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-a8) - 76 questions.
- [cortex-a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-a) - 8 questions.
- <strike>tag:cortex-m4 - 26 questions.</strike>
- <strike>tag:cortex-m0 - 20 questions.</strike>
- <strike>tag:cortex-a15 - 4 questions.</strike>
- [thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thumb) - 96 questions.
- [arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm) - 3300+ questions.
- [armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/armv7) - 246 questions.
- [armv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/armv6) - 120 questions.
- [arm7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm7) - 44 questions.
- [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64) - 42 questions.
- [arm9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm9) - 28 questions.
- <strike>tag:arm11 - 11 questions.</strike>
- [neon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neon) - 307 questions.
- [trust-zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trust-zone) - 13 questions.
- [gnu-arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-arm) - 6 questions.

I think that we should try to make synonyms from things to a generic *architechure*, with those being, armv6 (also arm11), armv7 (also cortex), and have a cortex-m, cortex-a.  I think that **thumb**, **neon** and **trust-zone** are useful on there own.  It is useful for people to browse these when they are learning a topic.  The overlap between **cortex-m3**, **cortex-m4** and **cortex-m0** seems to be too common and the occasional CPU specific question wouldn't harm a tag directly.  The **arm7** tag should be a synonym of **armv5** and possibly include things like **arm926** as a synonym.

Unfortunately, the community driven synonyms rarely seem to work well as people never [click on the link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) to see that they can vote on synonyms.  Also, the requirement for 5 up votes on a rarely used tag makes this difficult.  For the low question count tags, it is probably best just to edit the questions and re-tag them.

If we could agree on a consensus here, people would not waste time re-tagging questions.  At least, this is the way I believe things should work.  It is fine to tag with both **ARM** and another arm related tag.

Comment: I will promote the tags `cortex-m`, `cortex-a`, `armv5`, `armv6`, `armv7` and `arm64` and leave `thumb`, `trust-zone`, `neon` and `gnu-arm` as is.  So arm7, arm9, arm11, cortex-m? and cortex-a? will be merged with tags above.  Did someone have other suggestions?

Comment: This sounds good to me.

Comment: Still a mess >.<  I tried to nominate arm7 as a synonym of [arm], but: *Failed to propose synonym:
Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators*.  (There is no [armv5] tag anymore, so at least some progress has been made, but https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arm7 still has 83 questions, many of them *not* tagged [arm])

Comment: @PeterCordes  The synonyms are generally useless.  I proposed an 'interrupt' and 'irq' synonyms and it took over four years to be approved.  I just tried 'cortex-m' and 'cortex'm3', but is says some rule about 1.25x the post and disallows as well.